# Is there a way to evaluate model during training?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

I am working on a Machine Learning Project. I have set up a ML pipeline for various stages of project. The Pipeline goes like -

Data Extraction -> Data Validation -> Preprocessing -> Training -> Model Evaluation

Model Evaluation, takes place after training is completed to determine if a model is approved or rejected.
Now what I want is model evaluation to take place during training itself at any point.
Say at about when 60% of the training is complete, the training is stopped and model is evaluated, based on which if the model is approved, it resumes the training.

How can the above scenario be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

No you should only evaluate during the testing time if you tries to evaluate during train time like this you cant get the perfect accuracy of your model. As 60% training is done only the model is not trained on full dataset it might gave you high accuracy but your model can be overfitted model.